# Using select query in C#.NET for web service application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am not unable to understand the way in which a select * query is written while we create a web service using C#.NET to connect to an SQL Database.

Basically, I have 4 columns . I am taking a particular input from the user , which is an existing value of 1st column. Now depending on that value I want to select all the records of the remaining 3 columns. I need to write a SELECT * query but I don't in what form will I get those records. I have heard of SqlDataAdapter but then will it return me the records in a row-column format or do have to store the result in some sort of List and then use it for  other purposes.

Can someone please help me to understand how such a query can be written?

This code is wrong but it will help understand what I need

I want to get the records of other columns based upon my "where clause" condition

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.Services;
        using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
        using System.Xml.Linq;
        using System.Data.SqlClient;



   namespace statistics 
 {
       /// <summary>
/// Summary description for Service1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public int retrieve(String rollno)
    {

        int rows=0;

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123");
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
            String strsql = "SELECT * FROM checkrecord values WHERE rollno=@rollno";
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@rollno", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rollno;
            rows = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()         

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }

        return rows;
         }

      }
         }
```

Comment: So you want a SQL query to get data from the database, or do you want to know how to send SQL queries to the database? Or are you trying to figure out what form the results will come back in?

Comment: I want to know a SQL query to get the records from my columns in the database depending upon the condition in my "where" clause. Yes, I also want to knw how do I store the records, do I have to use a String array , or List or any data structure ? I require to use those records for other purposes

Comment: Sorry, his responses (and your comments to them) keep getting deleted, he doesn't seem to like negative feedback.

Comment: It doesn't look like the query you put as a comment on his post was valid.

Comment: @McKay : check the edit, my code is wrong. I just want to know the correct way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect to the database, then use SQLDataAdapter to send the user input SELECT query to the database. Something like,

SELECT col2,col3,col4 FROM yourtable WHERE col1 = ?

There are different ways to use the SQLDataAdapter, and specify the query and parameters. The SQLDataAdapter will return a DataSet that contains a DataTable. You can then use the DataSet or DataTable to populate the control of your choice (ie; DataGrid) with the results. There is a walk-through of this on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Based on your edit, you don't want to use ExecuteNonQuery. To get the rows you use ExecuteReader. Example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Can I store the Dataset in a String Array or an ArrayList?

Comment: The dataset is its own storage type

Comment: You could, but I guess it depends on how want to display the results. How do you plan on showing results to user? As McKay said the DataSet contains the results so you can use that to iterate results.

Comment: Basically, my idea is to return an Array containing all records because I want to call this webservice from an Android application. If I go with the usual Dataset can u tell me how do I get it from an Android application, only if u have done something like this ?

Comment: I haven't done this, but if I were to, I would consider having your WS output the data as JSON for the Android app to consume. That's the easiest way to go from the DataSet to and Android app. A few examples here: http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494
http://michaelearls.me/techblog/2010/12/29/bridging-the-gap-android-and-net-mvc-using-json

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the return type of the webservice? 
Yes, the database query will return you a list of the record values. With the .net webservices however, you can put these values into a custom class written by you, and the structure of this class will be included in your webservice.

```
[WebMethod]
public Myclass retrieve(String rollno)
{
return new Myclass("variable1", "variable2");
}
```

It will be included in the WSDL and thus can be implemented by any other application using your web service.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Can "variable1" be an array too ?

Comment: Yep, it will handle that for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the documentation for the class in question, in this case, the SQLDataAdapter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx

What I think you might want is to fill the results into a dataset.

Comment: Well in that case, am I going on the right way as far as my code is concerned ? Can I use an Array or an ArrayList to store the records?